# Jenkins + Git slow fetch and early EOF

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

**UPDATE:** In our case, we had a symlink point to a UNC share for jenkins workspace+builds. Overriding with a local directory for this project seemed to speed things up and resolve this peculiar issue. This question remains open as-is for anyone else wondering.

---

We have Jenkins setup to build several different MSBuild projects contained in enterprise GitHub instance.

This particular project simply won't finish fetching from our repository no matter what. Sturdy googling doesn't seem to help and so far the "solutions" I found do not appear to work (adjusting http.postBuffer), using cmd\git.exe and not bin\git.exe, etc.

What could be causing this problem?

```
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe config --local credential.helper store --file=\"C:\Users\S-STRA~1\AppData\Local\Temp\git4112069888826894851.credentials\" # timeout=10
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.example.net/orgname/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Failed to fetch from https://github.example.net/orgname/project.git
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:735)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.retrieveChanges(GitSCM.java:983)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.checkout(GitSCM.java:1016)
    at hudson.scm.SCM.checkout(SCM.java:485)
    at hudson.model.AbstractProject.checkout(AbstractProject.java:1282)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.defaultCheckout(AbstractBuild.java:610)
    at jenkins.scm.SCMCheckoutStrategy.checkout(SCMCheckoutStrategy.java:86)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:532)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1744)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:374)
Caused by: hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd\git.exe -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://github.example.net/orgname/project.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*" returned status code 128:
stdout: 
stderr: remote: Counting objects: 4967, done.[K
remote: Compressing objects:   0% (1/2307)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   1% (24/2307)   [K
remote: Compressing objects:   2% (47/2307)   [K
...keeps going...
    Receiving objects:  51% (2534/4967), 1.35 MiB | 6.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  51% (2549/4967), 1.35 MiB | 6.00 KiB/s   
Receiving objects:  51% (2575/4967), 1.36 MiB | 6.00 KiB/s   
fatal: early EOF
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: index-pack failed
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200

    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandIn(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1591)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.launchCommandWithCredentials(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1379)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.access$300(CliGitAPIImpl.java:86)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl$1.execute(CliGitAPIImpl.java:324)
    at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM.fetchFrom(GitSCM.java:733)
    ... 11 more
ERROR: Error fetching remote repo 'origin'
An attempt to send an e-mail to empty list of recipients, ignored.
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1):

"error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200"

Fairly certain that result=56 means that you got a network error or some issue while cloning the repo that prevented curl from downloading.

I suggest you use ssh instead of https to clone the repository if possible, it is more resilient and has less issues typically. Otherwise, there could be a firewall or some other network device (VPN or local anti-virus) causing the connection to stop in the middle of the clone.

Comment: No dice. Ended up actually running into more issues setting it up on Windows. The incredibly slow fetch still persist.

Comment: I should also mention that we had jenkins use a symlink to UNC path as workspace and build directories. Overriding to a local dir for this project seemed to speed things up and not cause issues. I'll leave the question open in case anyone else stumbles upon it.